# quick-sort 2500 element in an array

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

```
<?php
 // Recursive version:
function quicksort($seq) {
if(!count($seq)) return $seq;
$pivot= $seq[0];
$low = $high = array();
$length = count($seq);
for($i=1; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if($seq[$i] <= $pivot) {
        $low [] = $seq[$i];
    } else {
        $high[] = $seq[$i];
    }
}
return array_merge(quicksort($low), array($pivot), quicksort($high));
}
//Let's try some examples
$myarr = array(25,5,3,4,17,1,88,8);
$final = quicksort($myarr);
print_r($final);
$final = quicksort($final);
print_r($final);
$strarray = array("mark","wes","mj","bruce","ming","lance","vince");
var_dump(quicksort($strarray));

?>
```

Im new to php and i was wondering how can i make this loop more than 100 times. I have an array 2500 int element that i need to do a  quick sort on and display the results, however after 100 element it start giving the loop maximum error..........any idea?

Comment: you are just trying to program quicksort algorithm or you plan to use this function at future? If second, than: sort() uses an implementation of » Quicksort.

Comment: @viakondratiuk im just trying to program quick sort so i can time its execution  for a course im doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use some of the built-in sort functions. For instance: [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php). Check the [`Sorting Arrays`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) manual to see the complete list.